Growth variance formula is ignoring date filter and calculating for all dates
This is my data model for PBI.

This is my dax code for the growth measure.
Mth Sales Var = DIVIDE(
  SUMX(factSales, factSales[MonthStoreSalesThisYear]),
  SUMX(factSales, factSales[MonthStoreSalesLastYear])
  )
  -1

This is my expected output and what is being outputted instead. I have used page filters to filter the date[dimDate] to 2024/07/31 only.

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?
A few additional notes

the table only produces this unexpected result when i drag in my growth measure.If i take it out it otherwise aligns.
i've already checked my relationships between dim and fact tables are 1-to-many
Does this have anything to do with my dax for my growth measure? is it producing an output for every date and every store ignoring my page filter because i did not specify a row/filter context? ( i still don't really understand the contexts).


What happens if you remove the relationships to FactStoreCommentary? It looks like you might be trying to put two unrelated fact tables into the same visual

Maybe also post a data sample of the two fact tables and let us know which Table[Column] are being used in the visual. It looks like more likely to be a modeling issue than a DAX issue.

@alexrai93 removing all the relationships to the dimtables for FactStoreCommentary still yields the same unexpected result interestingly. Almost as if the relationships i've set up aren't even doing anything?

Can you confirm that you are using the [Date] field from Dim[Date] in the visual? Andl what if you remove the comments from the visual? It could cause problem if one has more records than the other for each date.

Yes, it is because it is returning a value because of the - 1.
Try:
Mth Sales Var = 
  var r =
    DIVIDE(
      SUMX(factSales, factSales[MonthStoreSalesThisYear]),
      SUMX(factSales, factSales[MonthStoreSalesLastYear])
    )
  return IF( NOT ISBLANK(r), r - 1)

